# Where on the Windows XP CD is the file PSCRIPT.HLP?

Tags: windows-xp

Trying to find this file on the CD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is on the CD inside \I386\DRIVER.CAB.
You may use [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) or other decompressing software to extract it.

You should be able to find the .cab file also in `C:\WINDOWS\Driver Cache\i386\driver.cab`.